# Raw Socket C TCP with Flags

Tags: c, linux, tcp, raw-sockets

i need clone a Packet i get with TCPDump in C,With RawSockets, Using `iph->` and `tcph->` in C.

This is 5 packets of example:

```
03:49.850665 IP SRCIP.22409 > DSTIP.80: Flags [.], ack 2897, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 20513654 ecr 3515597033], length 0
10:03:49.850667 IP SRCIP.22409 > DSTIP.80: Flags [.], ack 4345, win 296, options [nop,nop,TS val 20513654 ecr 3515597033], length 0
10:03:49.850669 IP SRCIP.22409 > DSTIP.80: Flags [.], ack 5793, win 319, options [nop,nop,TS val 20513654 ecr 3515597033], length 0
10:03:49.850671 IP SRCIP.22409 > DSTIP.80: Flags [.], ack 7241, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 20513654 ecr 3515597033], length 0
10:03:49.850673 IP SRCIP.22409 > DSTIP.80: Flags [.], ack 8689, win 364, options [nop,nop,TS val 20513654 ecr 3515597033], length 0
```

And i want to Do that kind of Packets in C, i using `sendto()` function for send packets, `tcph->` and `iph->`, With `int s = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);`, My code send SYN Packets with Checksum and anything correct, But i don't know how make this kind of packets, With that "Options".

If you need any another information of Code or Anything, Just ask it below.

Comment: Take a look at the description of tcp header at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure), I suppose you want to add options to TCP packets ? The problem is that the `struct tcphdr` has no member after the urgent pointer. You could maybe add manually the option part by allocating more memory than the size of the struct (not sure it's a good way to make it) ? You could maybe provide your code about the use of `struct tcphdr` and the call to `sendto` ?

Comment: @Missu https://hastebin.com/apuqibuvef.cpp See it.

Comment: I'm not an expert of Sockets and TCP but I suppose you could put your options at `datagram + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct tcphdr)`. Then you must take care that options are a part of the tcp header which mean they must be used to compute the checksum.